# Can a sequence guarantee the given order?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Using this Oracle sequence definition:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SPECIAL_COUNTER
  START WITH 100
  INCREMENT BY -1
  MAXVALUE 100
  MINVALUE 0
  NOCYCLE
  NOCACHE
  ORDER
  ;
```

Is it guaranteed, that this sequence will ALWAYS return

- each number once from 100 to 0
- in the given order from 100 to 0 and
- no single number will be obmitted and
- independent of multiple concurrent session in the very moment of the request

the correct number?

Comment: Yep.  See [oracle doc's](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) first paragraph basically says yes to all your conditions.

Comment: Even if let's say the sequence is called (does one _call_ a sequence?) in a pl/sql block and the transaction is then rolled back. Does this rollback include the sequence?

Comment: 3rd paragraph of above link: Sequence numbers are generated independently of tables, so the same sequence can be used for one or for multiple tables. ***It is possible that individual sequence numbers will appear to be skipped, because they were generated and used in a transaction that ultimately rolled back.*** so when rolled back, they are "Skipped" so you may have a gap.  But it was used, therefore not used again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the sequence will return each number once, starting with 100, progressively down to 0.

Yes, it will return them in order from 100 down to 0.

Correct, it will not skip any numbers.

Multiple sessions?   That depends.

Consider the following:

```
  create table junk ( id   number );

  CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SPECIAL_COUNTER
    START WITH 100
    INCREMENT BY -1
    MAXVALUE 100
    MINVALUE 0
    NOCYCLE
    NOCACHE
    ORDER
    ;

  -- in session 1 do the following:
  insert into junk
     select my_special_counter.nextval from dual;

  insert into junk
     select my_special_counter.nextval from dual;

  SQL> select * from junk;

          ID
  ----------
         100
          99

  SQL>

  -- in session 2 do the following:
  insert into junk
     select my_special_counter.nextval from dual;

  SQL> select * from junk;

          ID
  ----------
          98

  SQL> commit;

  -- in session 1 do the following:
  rollback;

  -- in session 3 do the following:
  SQL> select * from junk;

          ID
  ----------
          98

  SQL>
```

As you can see once you introduce multiple sessions, all kinds of fun things can happen. Numbers can be "lost" or "skipped" .. note that it is NOT the sequence doing it, but rather the session or whoever pulled the sequence value then subsequently drops it (ie job abends, and rollsback, logic error, etc.)

Also, if session 1 pulls sequence first, but session 2 commits first, others will "think" session 2 inserted a number "out of order" .. so to understand what you're after, we really need to understand your requirements in detail to advise further.

However, that should help you understand sequences properly. :)
Good luck!